# My previously working HTAccess no longer works

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

My HTAccess was working before. But I wanted to add an FTP section to the site. It is decided that all FTP will go in `/ftp` and all requests to `/ftp/...` will be internally redirected to `/ftp.php?dir=...` that handles authentication and such before using [`readfile(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Being a n00b at regex, I assumed this would work: (only the ftp section was added and the `|ftp` added)

```
RewriteEngine On

# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

# Match page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(cydia|firmware|scripts|site|ftp)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(robots.txt|ftp.php)
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /site/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

# Match FTP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?ftp
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /ftp.php?dir=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/*$ /site/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Basically, what I did was (I think) match `/ftp` as a true instead a false like above. However, this gives me a `500 Server Error` throughout the site (indicating a problem in the HTAccess). I'm sure this is a simple error, but I'm hoping you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that those too line will redirect everything starting with ftp (including ftp.php and this will create an infinite loop)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?ftp
RewriteRule ^?(.*)$ /ftp.php?dir=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Try replacing them with this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?ftp
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /ftp.php?dir=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I still got the server error. Using `^/?(.*)` fixed that, but now it shows the directory structure of `/ftp`.

Comment: Yes I didn't see that error (^? instead of ^/?). For the other thing, try removing this line : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: Your are welcome ) glad it worked (that line just says to not redirect if the request is made to a directory that does exist)